# SSL Related issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

We are facing problem while updating previous session with new value during login in Asp.Net MVC application on live server when we are using SSL.**It always display the previous logged in Session value but we are using session.abondon and also clearing session manually** on logout.But when we use ctrl+F5 it provide us with the correct current Session value. Without SSL it is working fine.Please suggest me  the appropriate answer.Do we need to change our web.config for this?

Comment: How do you check if it is the same value? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's browser caching problem so you can set no cache on you pages. If you are using MVC then you can use

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

on your action which is getting cached.